# Add class to WordPress widget ul

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to add a bootstrap class to widget ul. I have tried with the class arguments of  `register_sidebar`, but the class does not appear.

Is there any filter to do this type of modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted, but you could add a class to the widget (in the functions.php file) by adding `'class' => 'ulstyle',` to the `register_sidebar` and then in the css add

```
.ulstyle ul li 
{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The register_sidebar would be like:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Footer Widget Area', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
    'class'         => 'ulstyle',
    'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h1>',
) );
```

Comment: I need to add the class to ul element because is bootstrap class and it must be in "ul". I have already add the class => '', but this do not display the class on ul element.

Comment: Which widget exactly are you wanting the class to be added to?

Comment: I want to add to all widgets or widgets that have lists at least. I can do it with jQuery, but i would like to do by wordpress filter or php.